# Cant use thaw, Not a scalar string at ../../lib/Storable.pm but "REF" data

Tags: perl, hash

after execturin this code:

```
while(1){
    my $hashref = $mq->get($channel, $queue);
    next if (! defined($hashref));
    my %hash_ref = %{ thaw($hashref) };
    print Dumper($hash_ref);
    sleep(1);
}
```

I got

```
Not a scalar string at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/thaw.al) line 415, at ./accounting.pm line 21.
```

Also perl said that $hashref is REF(0x1bf3780). What a structure of data it is? How to convert it to hash?

I have two librarys (RabbitFoot and RabbitMQ), with simular code.
So, RabbitFoot output is:

```
 [x] Received  1234567
NAS-Port-Type
0Acct-Input-Octets
################################somedata
oeproverka      User-Name
################################somedata
Nov 12 2013 20:19:28 MSKEvent-Timestamp
        16777229NAS-Port
    0Acct-Delay-Time
```

and I can do with it like that(so its Ok string for thaw method)

```
my $hash_ref = thaw($body);
print $hash_ref->{'User-Name'};
```

BUT, rabbitMQ library output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'body' => '  12345678
ENAS-Port-Type
0Acct-Input-Octets
################################somedata
oeproverka      User-Name
Nov 12 2013 20:19:28 MSKEvent-Timestamp
################################somedata
0Acct-Delay-Time',
          'redelivered' => 1,
        };
```

take a look at this $VAR1 = { }, what is it? Why it is REF, and how to extract string that I need from there?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Yes, I have that. Code above is just a part of code

Comment: What makes you think `$mq->get($channel, $queue)` is something you can pass to `thaw`?  Where did the value come from?

Comment: it comes from RabbitMQ server. On server's side the hash was 'frozen'.

Answer (score 3):

`thaw` expects a string of bytes created by `freeze` or `nfreeze`, but you're passing some reference instead.

---

REF is a reference to a reference.

```
>perl -E"say ref \%h"
HASH

>perl -E"say ref \\%h"
REF
```

If the referenced reference is a reference to the desired hash, you'd use

```
my $hash = ${ $ref };       # Reference to hash
```

or

```
my %hash = %{ ${ $ref } };  # Wastefully copies the hash.
```

But you're probably better off fixing the code that gave you the hash ref ref to give you a hash ref instead.

Comment: Yep! This the name of this library is RabbitMQ(not work), but RabbitFoot with my $hash_ref = thaw($body); print $hash_ref->{'User-Name'}; works well!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
$hashref = $hashref->{body}; ####this string
my $output = thaw($hashref);
```